# Badge Requirements - Outspoken

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

The requirements for the silver [Outspoken](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/998/outspoken) badge are a little confusing to me:

`Posted 10 messages in chat that were starred by 10 different users`

Does this mean the badge can be achieved if

1. each message is starred once, but each star is from a unique person?
2. each message is starred 10 times (100 total stars) with 10+ unique persons across the board?
3. each message is starred 10 times (100 total stars) and each of those messages' stars must come from 10+ unique persons?
4. Something else entirely...?

Just trying to understand it clearly.

Comment: Clarification can often be found here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions

Comment: @jadarnel27 *"If you want to know, here's the precise definition: Consider the bipartite graph whose vertices are all your messages and all the users, and whose edges are the stars you received. So a user (vertex) and a message (vertex) are connected by an edge if and only if the given user has starred the given message. You are eligible for the Outspoken badge if and only if this graph has a matching number of at least ten."*  ...I'm still confused.

Comment: @JeremyBanksʬʬʬ - I finally got it. below is a layman explanation of what was said in the post. Make a little more sense?

Comment: @JeremyBanksʬʬʬ Ick...I did not look at the definition in there.  Usually they're pretty good, but that's awful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) article contains a brief explanation of the badge requirements.

**Answer:** In short it is possible to achieve this badge with only 10 chat posts if each post is tagged by a different unique person. However, each post counts only once, and each user only once.

**Explanation:** If my first message is starred by John Doe, the message cannot generate any more "unique persons" toward the 10 count, and John Doe cannot count toward starring any more of my posts.

See the mentioned article if you wish to see the exact graph described.